# Hibernate does not allow to save data with similar id

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm learning Spring and few days ago i started learning Hibernate. I have my studying project  where i need to create a shop with products. Here is entity class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cart")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")

    private int id;
    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private int quantity;
    @Column(name = "mask")
    private String mask;
    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;
```

So, i create interface

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CartRepository extends JpaRepository<Cart, Integer> {
}
```

and create controllers

```
@Autowired
    CartRepository cartList;

    @RequestMapping("/add-black-mask")
    public String addBlackMask() {
        cartList.save(new Cart(1, 1, "black", 3));

        return "masks/add-black-mask";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/add-build-mask")
    public String addBuildMask() {
        cartList.save(new Cart(2, 1, "build", 5));

        return "masks/add-build-mask";
    }


  @RequestMapping(value = "/save_product_to_cart")
    public ModelAndView saveProduct(@ModelAttribute(value = "cart")
                                            Cart cart, BindingResult result) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(cartList.count()));
        if (cart.getId() == 0) {
            cart.setId(index + 1);
            cartList.save(cart);
        } else {
            Cart cart1 = cartList.getOne(cart.getId());
            cart1.setMask(cart.getMask());
            cart1.setQuantity(cart.getQuantity());
            cart1.setPrice(cart.getPrice());
            cartList.save(cart1);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

Also, there are some other controllers for view, Thymeleaf etc, but its ok. My problem is - when i save my product 1 time - its ok, but when i save second - it didnt work( i think because i can't save 2 rows with similar ID) So it seems i have UNIQUE ID in my table and it can not be repeated. Question is - how can i delete unique id or change my code in any way? Thanks in advance!

p.s. i read some other topics here but it didnt help me.

Comment: Change `id` field to Integer. Hibernate works with wrapper objects. `price` should be Double, I suppose.

Comment: @Serj if you have record already in DB ..you can use saveOrUpdate() instead of save().

Answer (score 0):

when you use [`GENERATIONTYPE.IDENTITY`](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/) you are asking hibernate to let the database handle Ids for you, you should not set it yourself. you are changing the value of the id, just create a new product, set all the fields and inside a transactional context, save your product. Also always use wrapped versions of primitives for serialization purposes. (`Long` is an object but `long` is a primitive.) you can google boxing and unboxing and learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this question:
First of all, using annotations as our configure method is just a convenient method instead of coping the endless XML configuration file.

The `@Id`annotation is inherited from `javax.persistence.Id`， indicating the member field below is the primary key of current entity. Hence your Hibernate and spring framework as well as you can do some `reflect` works based on this annotation. for details please check [javadoc for Id](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html)

The `@GeneratedValue` annotation is to configure the way of increment of the specified column(field). For example when using `Mysql`, you may specify `auto_increment` in the definition of table to make it self-incremental, and then use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

in the Java code to denote that you also acknowledged to use this database server side strategy. Also, you may change the value in this annotation to fit different requirements.

#### 1. Define Sequence in database

For instance, Oracle has to use `sequence` as increment method, say we create a sequence in Oracle:

```
create sequence oracle_seq;
```

#### 2. Refer the database sequence

Now that we have the sequence in database, but we need to establish the relation between Java and DB, by using [`@SequenceGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html):

```
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq",sequenceName="oracle_seq")
```

`sequenceName` is the real name of a sequence in Oracle, `name` is what you want to call it in Java.  You need to specify `sequenceName` if it is different from `name`, otherwise just use `name`.  I usually ignore `sequenceName` to save my time.

#### 3. Use sequence in Java

Finally, it is time to make use this sequence in Java. Just add [`@GeneratedValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html):

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")
```

The `generator` field refers to which sequence generator you want to use. Notice it is not the real sequence name in DB, but the name you specified in `name` field of `SequenceGenerator`.

#### 4. Complete

So the complete version should be like this:

```
public class Cart
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seq",sequenceName="oracle_seq")        
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq")               
    private Integer id;
}
```

Now start using these annotations to make your JavaWeb development easier.

On top of that I would like you to understand all 4 ways of ID generation in hibernate. You can think of reading in your free time

1. GenerationType.AUTO
2. GenerationType.IDENTITY (your case)
3. GenerationType.SEQUENCE
4. GenerationType.TABLE {Rarely used nowdays}